# Rotating cube issues with rotation and Scaling

Tags: java, matrix, 3d, rotation, matrix-multiplication

I have been working on a project for a class for a while. I have spoken with the teacher and He says that he is unable to tell me why my program is doing what it is doing. The cube is having issues after being rotated, scaled the rotated again. If you scale then rotate the cube it has no issues running. However if you rotate(more then 5 degrees provides a clearer example) then scale the cube by any amount, then rotate the cube again the sides of the cube get messed up and start to display improperly. Any help or advice as to why would be very helpful. Thank you in advance. Part of the assignment is i cannot use Java3D, OpenGL or similar 3d projects.

```
I was unsure how to handle Posting multiple Class files so Here are the pastebin links.
My ControlPanel for input                http://pastebin.com/DPCPXqXC
My GraphicPanel for drawing              http://pastebin.com/RwzEGGGu
My GraphicsFrame for the panels          http://pastebin.com/ma6Z4hyk
My Points class for 3d Points            http://pastebin.com/6P7Vtg79
My MatrixOps class for matrix operations http://pastebin.com/QDmNnZFL
My CubeSides class for sides of cube     http://pastebin.com/i4pvKHqw
My Cube3D class that links the sides     http://pastebin.com/GVQTjiZ7
```

Comment: i quess this is offtopic here, since you don't have any concrete problem, ask your question -> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through your code with a debugger?